# Entity Framework With Database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

Here are the entities that i have...

```
Public Class Account
    Public Property AccountId As integer
    Public Property AccountDescription As String
    Public Property Transactions As List(Of Transaction)
End Class

Public Class Transaction
     Public Property TransactionId As Integer
     Public Property AccountId As Integer
     Public Property TransactionDescription As String
End Class
```

i would like to make it suc that when i do "db.Account.find(1)" for example it also loads in the list of all transactions which have the coresponding AccountId.  I'm not too sure what type of relationship this is?? anyway, right now i can do

```
Dim acct As Account = db.Account.Find(1)
acct.Transactions = from ts in db.transactions select ts where ts.AccountId = acct.accountid
```

but i know this is not the correct way, there must be a way to map this out so that entity can just load everything in one shot right?  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `db.Account.Include("Transactions").SingleOrDefault(1)` or put Transactions as virtual (I think it is Overridable in vb).

Comment: `Find` does not work after `Include`. It must be `SingleOrDefault` with a lambda expression for the key.